# Terminology: geometric sequences and geometric means

Tags: terminology, means

(I'll post my own answer to this one, but that should not deter others, since my answer is a surmisal.)

Why are geometric sequences called geometric sequences?  Whare are geometric means called geometric means?

Answer (score 2):

Take a square (side length $c$) and a rectangle (side lengths $a$ and $b$) of the same area $A$, then:

$$
A = c^2 = a b \iff c = \sqrt{a b}
$$

Otherwise read the Wikipedia articles on [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) and [harmonic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_progression_%28mathematics%29) and look for the remarks on the mean property for each.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the second of two line segments, $B$, is three times as long as the first $A$, and the third, $C$, is three times as long as the second.

Then the pair $A,B$ has the same geometric shape as the pair $B,C$.  That all pairs of consecutive terms in a sequence have the same geometric shape makes it a "geometric sequence".

Comment: IMHO this explanation would only stand if you had an equally smart explanation of why arithmetic mean is called arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The arithmetic mean $\mu_a$ of a sequence of numbers $a_1, \dots, a_k$ is the number such that $$ \Sigma a_i = \Sigma \mu_a. $$  If the operation of interest were multiplication rather than addition, the analogous definition would be $$ \Pi a_i = \Pi \mu_g $$ perhaps justifying the use of the term 'mean.'  I think this is geometric in the sense that products of lengths are the basis for Euclidean measure, and a cube of side length $\mu_g$ has the same volume as the ($k$-dimensional) rectangle with side lengths $a_1,\dots, a_k$.

Comment: I've modified the question a bit.

Comment: Aha.  Then I simply add my support for your original answer!  In particular, the entire k-tail $\Sigma_k^{\infty} r^n$ is a simple multiple of any other tail of the series.  This scaling property $$ r^N \Sigma_k^{\infty} r^n = \Sigma_{k+N}^{\infty} r^n $$ smacks of fractality.